# AngularJS - Extremely confused about how to use $resource actions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, server, angular-resource

I'm very new to AngularJS, and Web Development in general. I would really appreciate some help regarding the actions for client-server interactions and $resource

Here is a small snippet of code from my program

```
.factory('commentFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL) {
    var commentFac = {};

    comment.getComment= function() {
        return $resource(baseURL + "comments/", null);
    };

    return commentFac;
}])
```

In the following controller, $scope.feedback elements are being changed with the ng-model directive in the webpage

```
.controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', 'commentFactory', function($scope, commentFactory) {
    $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };        
    $scope.sendFeedback = function() {

        commentFactory.getComment().save(
            $scope.feedback,             //What I want to send back to the server
            function() {       //Callback functions. No idea what to put here

            },
            function() {

            }
        );
}])
```

How will $scope.feedback be stored in the server? How would i be able to later access the comments when needed? I'm almost !00% certain my .save action is icorrect, but I can't seem to find online how I'm supposed to use it. What do I put in the callback functions?

I'm sorry that this is such a rookie questions, but this is honestly a little difficult to comprehend.

Edit: I changed the line

```
return $resource(baseURL + "comments/", null);
```

to

```
return $resource(baseURL + "comments/:id", null);
```

and it worked. I'm not sure why though. Would appreciate an explanation and answers to my above questions.

Thanks again

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound: I tried that site. It's a little difficult to follow.

Comment: how they get stored on server depends on how your backend code handles different methods like PUT, POST etc